# Where can i download "What are the chances?:Probability made clear" lectures videos?

Tags: probability, reference-request

I want to learn probability through lectures videos and i would like to know where i can download **The Teaching Company** videos for the course titled **"What are the chances ? :Probability made clear "** I will appreciate if there is anyone who knows the links for the download.

Comment: Or are you asking where you can download them for free, illegally?

Comment: No illegally, through some torrents software

Comment: I don't understand.  It looks like you're saying what I said was wrong, but then you say what you are going to do which is EXACTLY what I was talking about.  Please clarify.  Downloading this through some torrents software would be illegal.  If it is $169.95, as Charles says below, it's not going to also be available for free, legally.  If it's free, it's almost certainly illegal.

Comment: I'm quite sure he's acknowledging that it will be illegal. Perhaps a bit of a language barrier somewhere.  Shouldn't have started his sentence with "no."

Comment: @JBeardz That's what I took it to mean, as well, but I wanted to clarify.  Perhaps if the OP's goal is free videos, answers might include other free videos on probability?  Byron has already provided the least expensive ways of obtaining these specific videos, legally.

Comment: @Graphth Sure, they can include other videos. Free, or paid. About math, or not. Any kind of spam. Until this question is closed, as it should have been 3.5 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the videos on the website of the editor: http://www.thegreatcourses.com/tgc/courses/course_detail.aspx?cid=1474, the direct download is $169.95.

Comment: The Teaching Company regularly offers their products on sale, at prices much more suitable for the individual. If you keep watching their website, eventually every course comes around and is offered on sale for some weeks. The sale price is often 30% of the regular price, or less. Keep your eyes open!

Answer (score 4):

Courses from the Teaching Company are often available in public libraries. Check with your local library.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment, if your goal is to obtain these videos for free, it's most likely illegal, and we can't help you with that.  But, Byron has mentioned that perhaps you could borrow them from a public library, or you could buy them at a discounted price if you wait for a sale.  The next best option appears to be other free probability videos online.  You could just google for these, but a couple sources for some FREE probability videos would be:

http://patrickjmt.com/

http://www.khanacademy.org/

Neither appears to go too far into probability.  A better option would probably be to go to YouTube and search for "probability lectures".  There appear to be several series of videos you can watch.